# jMonkeyEngine - my mouse and my key arrows are reversed and

Tags: jmonkeyengine

I'm new to jMonkeyEngine so I hope my question is not too much stupid. 
I followed this tutorial step by step : http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:beginner:hello_simpleapplication

But unfortunately, when I tested the key arrows, I found out that the left key arrow brings me at right, the top one to the bottom,...

How can I fix this? Otherwise, how can I configure the key arrows and the mouse to move to the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Are you entirely sure thats what's happening. The arrow keys move **you** upwards and so move the **box** downwards

Comment: @Richard Tingle, So you mean that I'm not moving the object but my direction of view, right?

Comment: Exactly, you're technically moving the camera up and down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mouse and keyboard control the camera, not objects in the scene (by default at least). This makes a lot more sense when there is more than one object in the scene, a street for example.

When you press up you move the camera upwards; as a result all objects in the scene appear to go downwards. The same for all the other directions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, I can go ahead :)

Comment: @user1847726 Glad to have helped!